# Python script with Robot framework fails

Tags: python, com, adodb, robotframework

I'm running a script which written in python 2.7 and runs with Robot 2.8.4

It fails with error message:

Windows COM Error: Dispatch('ADODB.Connection') failed

OperationalError: (InterfaceError("Windows COM Error: Dispatch('ADODB.Connection') failed.",), 'Error opening connection to "Driver={SQL Server};Server=dbm8-data190\inst01;Initial Catalog=dbmDILMessagesArchive"')

What's wrong? I ran it on 64-bit Windows 7 enterprise machine

Comment: Can you provide more information? Which part of your script is executing the DB call? Looks like a failure connecting to the DB server.

Comment: Can you connect to 'dbm8-data190\inst01'?

Comment: This issue resolved:
1. I uninstalled the 64-bit of Python and installed a 32-bit installer
2. I ran an extension called pywin32-219.win32-py2.7. I've founded it somewhere on the net

Comment: 3. The connection to the db wasn't really the problem. I think It just didn't recognized some of the files on 64-bit Python version that asked for access to the db.
4. Thanks for your help